# calculate closed sets of keys and values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have a file that is run through a program to create duplicate groups based on the company name and address. If records are found to have the same company name and address they are assigned a 'dupe group' number. In a second pass we create dupe groups based only on the phone number. These phone number dupes are given a dupe group number as well but in a separate field.

I'm now in the process of tying to combine these two dupe group fields to create a single dupe group number that is based on either the company/address and/or the phone number.

For example if the 'ABC company' at '123 Main St.' has 10 records in the company dupe group and some of those records have a phone number, and that phone number is also in a dupe group of a different company  say 'ABC company' at '456 South St' I want to give all the records in both dupe groups a single id.

The original data is in a single file with a field for company/address dupes and another field for phone dupes.

To do this I created two dictionaries. 
One is the PhoneDupe dict where the 'key' is the phone dupe group number and the 'value' is a list of all company dupe groups that are within that phone dupe group.

The other is a CompanyDupe dict where the 'key' is the company dupe group number and the 'value' is a list of all phone dupes groups within that company dupe.

Here is a small sample:

```
PhoneDupes = {8715: [7125], 8710: [7125, 18684], 8719: [7067, 7101, 7125, 7342, 8068]}

CompanyDupes = {8068: [8719], 7342: [8719], 7125: [8719, 8715, 8710], 7067: [8719], 18684: [8710], 7101: [8719]}
```

In this example the first item in the PhoneDupes is #8715 this has a value of 7125. I then need to take that value and search for it in the CompanyDupes dict. When I do that I will find that 7125 has the values [8719, 8715, 8710]. I then need to take each of those values (except for the 8715 because I've already searched for that) and look for them in the PhoneDupe dict. When I search for the first (8719) I'll get [7067, 7101, 7125, 7342, 8068] and when I search the second (8710) I'll get [7125, 18684] (again I can ignore the 7125 because I've already searched for that).

This has to keep going back and forth until I find all associated records.

The goal is to end up with a list of lists of Company dupe groups that should be combined.

I'm assuming the best way to do this is some kind of recursive function that keeps going back and fourth until all records are collected. I'll also need to pass a list of id's already searched for.

**Does anyone know of a good approach to take to compare two dictionaries in this way?
Or if there might be a better way to do this?**

So far I'm trying to pass one phonedupe id into a function along with the two dicts, have it grab the value and then pass that back into the function but with the two dicts reversed then look through the second dict for phonedupe id's. I also am passing a list to collect the id's or records already searched. Eventually it will get to the point where it can't find any more id's that are not already in the list and then return the list back up through all the iterations to produce a final list with all the associated record id's.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Sorry that my question was so long, I wanted to make sure readers could understand what I was trying to do.

Yes, the small sample I used is all dupes. I just grabbed all the records that I already knew were dupes to make sure it grabbed them all. I've tested what I have on the full data and it is working.

because each time I call the function from withing the function I am reversing the two dictionaries I added the flag which checks the length of the dict so I know whether to add to the output file or not.

I didn't have any code to enter here when I first posted the question but I was able to get something to work so I'll post it now. In this case the 'pdupe' is the phone dupe and 'dupe' is the company dupe

```
def test_rollup(id,comb_list,dict1,dict2,flag):
for dupe in dict1[id]:
    if dupe not in comb_list and comb_list != None:
        if flag == len(dict1):
            comb_list.append(dupe)
            test_rollup(dupe,comb_list,dict2,dict1,flag)
        else:
            test_rollup(dupe,comb_list,dict2,dict1,flag)
return comb_list

for id in pdupe:
    test_rollup(id,comb_list,pdupe,dupe,len(pdupe))
    if sorted(comb_list) not in master_list:
        master_list.append(sorted(comb_list))
    comb_list = []
```

Comment: [Your question is looooooooong](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I tried to process the data that you used as an example, and it appears that you have a trivial case here. That is: every record is duplicated, this appears to all be a single connected company. Can you confirm whether that is correct? If so, I'm not sure what exactly to output. The only thing that makes sense is a list of phonedupes (8719
8715
8710) and a list of company dupes: (
8068
7067
7101
7125
7342
18684)

Comment: tl;dr. Also, show us some of your code.

Comment: @TomRose, Yes you are correct. This is a single connected company that I was using to test with. The output that I need is just what you listed for company dupes [8068 7067 7101 7125 7342 18684]. The full data set has many companies and also many unique records. See my edit above for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find closed sets `c in C` st for each `n` in `c`, every `p` in `PhoneDupes[n]` and every `co` in `CompanyDupes[n]` is also in `c`.

As a first pass, let's build some sets of number we know are associated:

```
PhoneDupes = {8715: [7125], 8710: [7125, 18684], 8719: [7067, 7101, 7125, 7342, 8068]}

CompanyDupes = {8068: [8719], 7342: [8719], 7125: [8719, 8715, 8710], 7067: [8719], 18684: [8710], 7101: [8719]}
[set([n]+PhoneDupes.get(n, [])+CompanyDupes.get(n, [])) for n in PhoneDupes]
```

What should we do with these? Probably the exact same thing:

```
import itertools
def closure(inset, acc = set()):
    new = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain(PhoneDupes.get(n, []),CompanyDupes.get(n, []))  for n in inset))
    really_new = (new - inset) - acc
    if not really_new: return inset|acc
    else: return closure(really_new, inset|acc)

closed_sets = [closure(set([n]+PhoneDupes.get(n, [])+CompanyDupes.get(n, []))) for n in PhoneDupes]
#=> [set([8068, 8710, 8715, 7342, 8719, 7125, 7067, 18684, 7101]), set([8068, 8710, 8715, 7342, 8719, 7125, 7067, 18684, 7101]), set([8068, 8710, 8715, 7342, 8719, 7125, 7067, 8684, 7101])]

closed_sets ==  [closure(s) for s in closed_sets]
#=> True
```

You'll note that in fact every such set is the same, and appears to include every number of from your sample input. That's in the nature of finding closed sets - if there aren't disjoint subsets, then there is in fact only one closure.

Let's manufacture two disjoint subsets, and see what happens:

```
PhoneDupes2  = {k+1:[n+1 for n in v] for k,v in PhoneDupes.iteritems()}
CompanyDupes2  = {k+1:[n+1 for n in v] for k,v in CompanyDupes.iteritems()}
PhoneDupes.update(PhoneDupes2)
CompanyDupes.update(CompanyDupes2)
closed_sets = [closure(set([n]+PhoneDupes.get(n, [])+CompanyDupes.get(n, []))) for n in PhoneDupes]
#deduplicate closed_sets
frozenset(frozenset(s) for s in closed_sets)
#=> frozenset([frozenset([8068, 8710, 8715, 7342, 8719, 7125, 7067, 18684, 7101]), frozenset([8069, 8711, 8716, 7343, 8720, 7126, 7068, 18685, 7102])])
```

If you only want to get the values from CompanyDupes:

```
def closure_co(inset, acc = set(), co_acc=set()):
    newphone = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(PhoneDupes.get(n, []) for n in inset))
    newco = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(CompanyDupes.get(n, [])  for n in inset))
    really_new = ((newphone|newco) - inset) - acc
    if not really_new: return co_acc
    else: return closure_co(really_new, inset|acc, co_acc|newco)
```

Comment: I posted my solution above. Your answer is not exactly what I was trying to do, because I only want to include the numbers from the company dupe in my output.

Comment: @user1464473 This is still not clear, but the question is also not on hold. You can easily alter my solution to separately accumulate from the two different source sets.

Comment: @user1464473 In fact, I have just done so. I think you can work out any modifications yourself.